# Website doesn't display after uploading the Yeoman created site

Tags: html, css, web-services, server, directory

I am using Yeoman to create a static website, which created a file structure like:

```
-app
   index.html
  -css
    style.css
  -js
    script.js
Gruntfile.js
README.md
bower.json
package.json
```

I used filezilla to send this to my server (using bluehost) but nothing seems to be displaying? when I try to hit the website. (ex. whatever.com)

Is it because my 'index.html' lives inside the app directory? Should I only host my app diretory so 'index.html' is in the root directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with location of index.html but not quite. Your file structure should look like:

```
[document root]
index.html
- css (a directory of the root)
    style.css
- js (also a directory of the root same as css)
    script.js
    Gruntfile.js
    README.md
    bower.json
    package.json
```

Note in the above structure, there is no -app folder. You can test the above by using your web browser and pointing to http://yoursite.domain/app and see if that displays.

If that does not solve the issue, then you may be uploading to somewhere outside of the document root for your web server in which case you should find out where that is. Best place to ask about that would be on either https://serverfault.com/ or on https://superuser.com/. Good luck.

Comment: ahh got it! Thanks! For futuer references, I would hate for Yeomen to keep creating file structure like this all the time. Is there a better solution to doing so without me trying to re-arrange the file structure all the time?

Comment: When you use FileZilla, select the contents of the app folder and copy that to the server. If my answer helped you, would appreciate if you accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the question. Thanks.